# Jquery - adding a dynamically added control from getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, draggable

I am having a problem assigning a control to dynamically added elements (inside the JSON function).

The code is working fine but when I add $('div.prnt').append("hello"); inside the JSON it then doesn't assign the $("div.text").draggable(); to it. When I take the JSON function away and i'm using just $('div.prnt').append("hello"); it works straight away.

I imagine the JSON function is stopping the elements from being added before the draggable control is called.

```
<style>
    div.prnt div.test
    {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var serviceurl = "WebServices/BusinessCardStudio.svc/gettextobjects/3457/17/17/1064/709/600/399";

        $.getJSON
        (
            serviceurl,
            function (data)
            {
                $.each(data, function (i, item)
                {
                    $('div.prnt').append("<div class='object text'>hello</div>");
                });
            }
        );

        $("div.text").draggable();
    });
</script>
<div class="prnt">
</div>
```

Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it in the success of ajax, so that it will ensure its done after the ajax is completed

```
$.getJSON
            (
                serviceurl,
                function (data)
                {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item)
                    {
                        $('div.prnt').append("<div class='object text'>hello</div>");
                    });
               $("div.text").draggable(); 
               }
            );


        });
```

Answer (score 3):

AJAX is *asynchronous*.

The `getJSON()` call will return immediately, and your `draggable()` call will run before the server replies.

You need to move the `draggable()` call into the callback.
This is why the callback exists in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`$("div.text").draggable();` is called immedately after your JSON request starts.  Then later, the server responds with JSON and executes the function you pass to it.  So you are making something draggable that doesnt exist yet.

Put the draggable call in the callback function and you should be good.